# Count within in statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a query similar like this.

```
SELECT t.* FROM
    (SELECT 
      `user_bookmarks`.`id` AS `user_bookmark_id`,
      `bookmark_id`,
      `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`,
      `bookmark_url`,
      `bookmark_website`,
      `bookmark_title`,
      `bookmark_preview_image`,
      `bookmark_popularity`,
      `category_id`,
      `category_name`,
      `pdf_txt_flag`,
      `youtube_video`,
      `content_preview`,
      `snapshot_preview_image`,
      `mode` ,
       @r:= CASE WHEN category_id = @g THEN @r+1  ELSE @r:=1 END `rank` ,
       @g:=category_id
    FROM
      `user_bookmarks` 
      LEFT JOIN `bookmarks` 
        ON `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` = `bookmarks`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `categories` 
        ON `user_bookmarks`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` 
      JOIN (SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t1
    WHERE `category_id` IN (164, 170, 172) 
    ORDER BY category_id
    ) t
    WHERE t.rank <=6
```

it's refer to this answer. 
[This is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112681/mysql-limit-with-in-statement/25112797#25112797)

Can we count total number of  result in each **Category_id** in above query. Can we do it in mysql itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a bit of a trick:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
              @r := (CASE WHEN category_id = @g THEN @r ELSE rank END) as maxrank,
              @g := category_id
      from (<inner query here>) t
      order by category_id, t.rank desc
     ) t
where t.rank <= 6;
```

The idea is to re-sort the data descending and then copy the rank across the rows for each category.

Comment: Can you please tell, i am new to mysql . i am not able to implement on above query

Comment: @MohitKumar . . . There were two syntax errors (a lingering `case` and missing comma).  Do you still have problems with it?

Comment: Actually i want to implement it on above question. The Above solution is working fine. need counter